# The calculation of dyadic addition

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, harmonic-analysis

$\newcommand{\dplus}{\mathbin{\dot{+}}}$
Denote the dyadic addition by $\dplus$. For any $x,y\in[0,1)$ with
$$
x=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x_k}{2^{k+1}} 
\quad\mbox{and}\quad 
y=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{y_k}{2^{k+1}},
$$
where, for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, $\,x_k,y_k\in\{0,1\}$,
define
$$
x \dplus y := \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{|x_k-y_k|}{2^{k+1}}
$$
and for any measurable subset $E$ of $[0,1)$, define
$$
y \dplus E := \{y \dplus x:\, x\in E\}.
$$
Let $I=\left[\frac{m}{2^k}, \frac{m+1}{2^k}\right)$ be a dyadic interval, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+,\, 0\leq m\leq 2^k-1$.

How to prove that, for any $l<k$ and $l\in\mathbb{Z}_+$,
$$
I \dplus 2^{-l-1}
$$
is a dyadic interval ?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Yeah, If $I=[0,2^{-k})$, then for $l<k$, $I\dot{+}2^{-l-1}\in\left[2^{-l-1},2^{-k}+2^{-l-1}\right)$, but for the general case, how to prove it?

Comment: Notation: wrap your dotted plus sign in `\mathbin` to let LaTeX know that it's a binary operator, which gives better spacing. Compare `x \dot{+} y` $x \dot{+} y$ to `x \mathbin{\dot{+}} y` $x \mathbin{\dot{+}} y$.